# Stagnation flow pressure integral

Tags: potential, flow

Imagine a water jet stagnates at a wall as shown below.
[image]

If we intentionally select our control volume boundary just above the floor, the pressure integral along the floor, should be equivalent to rate of change of momentum.

Given the potential $\psi = Vxy$, the $x$ component of velocity at the floor becomes $2Vx$.

By applying Bernoulli equation, the integral becomes,

$P_{tot} = P_0 - 2\rho V^2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2$

But this integral clearly diverges.
What is my mistake here , can anyone point this out to me ?

Thanks

*EDIT : As suggested by D.Halsey this equation only describes the flow at the vicinity of the stagnation point. If I'am to prove that this pressure integral sums up to the rate of change of momentum change what are the other possible ways of doing this.?*

Answer (score 1):

Your equation describes the flow behavior only in the immediate neighborhood of the stagnation point, so it cannot be used to calculate the total force on an extended wall.

And by the way, ψ is the streamfunction, not the potential, but it is equally as useful for 2-D potential flow problems.

Comment: Hi D. Halsey, Thanks for the answer. It makes sense. If I may add to the original question do you know a method to model this case ?